# iptables on busybox

Tags: linux, iptables, busybox

I have busybox installed as a 'starter' package on my embedded linux board and I also need to use iptables to configure some firewall rules.

Is there a way to get access to iptables from the busybox shell?

Otherwise, how can I exit busybox shell to get to the iptables command?

Thank you.

Comment: check if it's in your path. iptables is usually in /sbin or similar and super-user only directories usually aren't in the path by default.

Comment: From my busybox shell, I find no evidence of iptables. Example, when I do a whereis iptables, it returns empty. Does than mean iptables is not installed properly or it cannot be accessed from inside busybox shell?

Comment: Thanks Marc .. sorted .. I did a newbie error, forgot to extract the new RFS to the NFS export directory! Apologies ... moving ahead now.

Answer (score 1):

（1）First you need to how to modify the kernel， install modules and applications in Busybox environment.

（2）Then you can config the kernel to support Iptables (most in menu of network/netfilter),you can build those kernel modules as ko modules or part of kernel image.

（3）go to homepage to netfilter to get application souce code. Build and install.

（4）modprobe the ko (for example)

```
modprobe iptable_filter
modprobe ip_tables
```

（5）try your IPTABLES....If meet problem, you may goto step 2 to make some change.